# What does it mean for Spring Reactor's Mono to return empty?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

From its documentation, it states that Mono returns empty when it "completes without emitting any items". What does it mean to complete without emitting any items? Does it mean that it never sent any request or?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation. Generally, for reactive data access libraries it means that the request/query was executed but yielded no results. However, this is not always the case as there are alternative behaviours like returning a default value or returning a `Mono` with error. Always consult the relevant library (e.g.: Spring Data) documentation to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering from the perspective of "what does it mean in terms of behavior", not "what does the empty Mono behavior means in terms of business logic":*

`Mono` is a `Publisher`, an interface that is defined to emit a set of signals to its `Subscriber`: `onNext`, `onComplete`, `onError`.

In the case of `Mono` the possible combinations are restricted:

- `onNext` followed by `onComplete` (something was produced and we're done)
- `onError` (something went wrong)
- `onComplete` (nothing was produced but we're done)

The last one is the empty case you're wondering about: an empty `Mono` is one that never emits the `onNext` signal but rather simply emits `onComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Simon's complete answer (why do I do that, hm?)
One typical use case of Mono returning empty is filtering. Think of it like if you need to do something in `if then else` style, in terms of Mono you *could* use `.filter` for `then` and `.switchIfEmpty` for `else`.

To understand the logic behind, for me it was also useful to look onto `interface MonoSink<T>` apidoc. It basically says the same: you can either complete without value, or with it, see two overloaded `success` methods.